# Rails app moved to production server gives "dump format error for symbol" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, passenger

I've just moved my rails app from the development to deployment server.
I've installed passenger, but I wanted to try with `rails s` to make sure all was running fine (this is the first time I develop and deploy a rails application).

Specs are: Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM, mod_passenger, Rails 3.2.3. All installed correctly and I've also enabled the Apache module. By the way something is going wrong (passenger keeps sayng "Error message: Unknown key: class".)

Running `rails s` is giving a weird error listed above `dump format error for symbol(0x45)`

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/_links.haml (2.2ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (11.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 110ms

ActionView::Template::Error (dump format error for symbol(0x45)):
    8:     / HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements
    9:     /[if lt IE 9]
    10:       = javascript_include_tag "http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"
    11:     = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
    12:     /%link(href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon")
    13:     /%link(href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon")
    14:     /%link(href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72")
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__3524679841439843142_22055600'
```

What does it mean? Googling it seems a flash[] error but I can't really understand what should I do here.

Waiting for some suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Can you paste the code of application.html.haml?

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/iAXARraY
(I'm using twitter bootstrap so I followed a common page style)

Answer (score 46):

Had the same problem.  Try removing your [app]/tmp dir.  It seems to be trying to unmarshal some borked files.

Comment: This was it for me as well.  I think it had to do with upgrading some of my gems.

Comment: This worked for me as well - after did 'replace all in files' in an editor.

Comment: This error was also introduced to my app by using the "replace all in files" feature to change some variables.  It tampered with files in the tmp/cache dir, creating this issue.

Comment: Similar to Steve I did a replace all and caused issues. My specific error code was (0x70). Clearing cookies as others suggested did not work. This answer worked for me although I believe I had to reboot as I encountered another error about one of my JS libraries not being found.

Answer (score 26):

Change an asset from new.js to new.js.coffee and received this error when trying to render a view which was trying to render new.js:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (dump format error for symbol(0x6d))
```

I figured it was something related to the tmp files (thanks to the comments in this thread). I ran:

```
bundle exec rake tmp:clear
```

And I was good to go!

Comment: This worked for me (but, yes, it appears a little mysterious.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I inserted "haml-rails" under the `:assets` pipeline, so it was not able to find HAML on the production environment.

To be honest I'm surprised that just removing `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag` it was still rendering the html.

By the way I fixed it by moving `haml-rails` out from the `assets` scope.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when I removed a bunch of unused .coffee files from my assets.

I resolved the issue by running:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=<environment>
```

And then restarting the server.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't look like a passenger error, my guess would be a problem with your HAML.  Try removing 8, 9, and 10, and see if it renders.  If it does, that will let you narrow down the problem.

Comment: I needed to remove all `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag`. It works, but without any style or js (obviously).

What's wrong here?

Comment: Try replacing if ie with the surround helper as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107681/ie-conditional-comments-in-haml

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and the fix was to run `git clean -dfx`