# Rails 3.2.10 dump format error for symbol(0x46)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am getting the following error:

```
dump format error for symbol(0x46)
```

in my rails application after having implemented the following method:

in model:

```
   def common_friends(user)
        (self.following & user.following).count
    end

    def top_5_by_shared_friends
     following.sort_by{|user| common_friends(user)}.reverse.first(5)
    end
```

and in my view:

```
<%= render :partial => 'users/user_profile_summary', :collection => @shared_friends, :as => :user %>
```

in my controller:

```
@shared_friends = @current_user.top_5_by_shared_friends
```

Now I only get this error when I render the partial in my view. I.e. if I remove the "render partial" line the application loads fine, except of course it doesn't show the content I would like it to.

See below the application stack trace:

```
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/session_store.rb:60:in `load'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/session_store.rb:60:in `unmarshal'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/session_store.rb:137:in `data'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/session_store.rb:315:in `block in get_session'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb:50:in `silence'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/session_store.rb:307:in `get_session'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:251:in `load_session'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:49:in `block in load_session'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:57:in `stale_session_check!'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:49:in `load_session'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:135:in `load!'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:127:in `load_for_read!'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:64:in `has_key?'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:258:in `ensure in call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:259:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1662995712724838230__call__2192866322429324249__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
unicorn (4.6.2) bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
/home/lgorse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `load'
/home/lgorse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `<main>'
/home/lgorse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/lgorse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I've identified the cause of the error:

in one part of my partial, I call on:

```
<li class = "follower_count"><%= pluralize(user.followers.count, "follower") %></li>
```

simply placing user.followers.count yields the error. This is obviously conflicting with my model methods but I don't understand why at all.

Here is the Relationship model - followers relies on :reverse_relationship and I think the error occurs there but I'm not sure why it happens here only rather than other parts of the program where I also call followers:

```
has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id", :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Relationship"
    has_many :following,  :through => :relationships, :source => :followed
    has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out a hack to get the site working. Here it is:

In my controller, I replaced:

```
@shared_friends = @current_user.top_5_by_shared_friends
```

with:

```
@shared_friends = User.find(session['user_id']).top_5_by_shared_friends
```

This means the app has to tap into the database one more time, which is redundant since it already does this based on session['user_id'] in a before_filter. But for some reason this passes correctly and the app runs properly.

If anyone has a real solution, rather than a hack like this, please chime in.

Otherwise I will accept my own answer - given others may solve the same problem with the same hack.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `rake tmp:clear` and the problem resolves itself.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552925/rails-app-moved-to-production-server-gives-dump-format-error-for-symbol-error)