# Conditional HTML tag in HAML

Tags: html, haml

How would I format HAML to output a style similar to the conditional HTML tags used for cross-browser targeting?

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

If I add a conditional, it wraps entire page in the conditional as well. I thought about using HAML's `:plain` filter at the top and manually adding `</html>` at the bottom, but this seems less than ideal to me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The first three of these are pretty simple, as they are just plain HTML comments and you can use the [Haml support for conditional comments](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#conditional_comments_):

```
/[if lt IE 8] <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en">
/[if IE 8] <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en">
/[if IE 9] <html class="no-js ie9 oldie" lang="en">
```

The [last one is a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107681/ie-conditional-comments-in-haml/9119406#9119406). Breaking it down, what you want is two comments surrounding the `html` opening tag, so the second comment is the first content of the `html` element. Also you can’t use the Haml syntax for conditional comments, you’ll have to use a literal comment. In Haml this would look like:

```
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
%html{:class => 'no-js', :lang => 'en'}
  <!--<![endif]-->
```

This will produce HTML like this:

```
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html class='no-js' lang='en'>
  <!--<![endif]-->
```

If you wanted you could use the [whitespace removal syntax](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_) to make the generated HTML more like your example:

```
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
%html{:class => 'no-js', :lang => 'en'}<>
  <!--<![endif]-->
```

Putting it all together:

```
!!!
/[if lt IE 8] <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en">
/[if IE 8] <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en">
/[if IE 9] <html class="no-js ie9 oldie" lang="en">
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
%html{:class => 'no-js', :lang => 'en'}<>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  content here
```

which produces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="no-js ie9 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class='no-js' lang='en'><!--<![endif]-->
content here</html>
```

An alternative technique would be to use [Haml’s surround helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#surround-instance_method):

```
= surround "<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class='no-js' lang='en'><!--<![endif]-->", "</html>" do
  content here
```

Comment: wonderful answer. props for the surround alternative as well.

Comment: @matt Shouldn't that last bit be: `<!--[if gt IE 8]|!(IE)]><!-->`?

Comment: @nozpheratu Do you mean should it have `!(IE)` part? Not necessarily – non IE browsers will ignore the condition anyway and render the content, and IE browsers will be covered by the existing clause. You could add it for documentation I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!doctype html>
/[if lt IE 8] <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en">
/[if IE 8] <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en">
/[if IE 9] <html class="no-js ie9 oldie" lang="en">
/ [if gt IE 9]><!
%html.no-js{:lang => "en"}
  / <![endif]
```

Comment: pretty close! though the last line is a bit different. will probably still work though?

Comment: Tested; the result is exactly the same as the HTML you wanted (except obviously the <html>s are not aligned; no biggie) and it has the upside of syntax consistency. If you use Sublime Text, you will definitely want the HTML2Haml plugin - it parsed my whole layout page perfectly, including this exact example you wanted (I, too, was using Boilerplate). For a web version, http://html2haml.heroku.com/