# Rails - HAML "surround" for !IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I am doing a rails app and I found bit issue following what [@matt suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107681/ie-conditional-comments-in-haml?answertab=votes#tab-top), I am finding below issues:

HAML

```
!!!
= surround '<!--[if !IE]> -->'.html_safe, '<!-- <![endif]-->'.html_safe do
  %html.no-js{:lang => 'en'}
  %head
  %body
```

Here is how the browser render the HTML (without ending  tag at very end and adds it at declaring line itself)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if !IE]> --><html class='no-js' lang='en'></html>
<head>..</head>
<body>..</body>
```

So, here is the code that's working fine for me, but is there a way to make above code work ?

```
!!!
:plain
  <!--[if !IE]><!-->
%html.no-js{:lang => 'en'}
  / <![endif]
```

Comment: I think you’re looking for something like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868977/conditional-html-tag-in-haml, which isn’t quite the same as the one you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's causing the problem, but `head` and `body` should be inside the `html` tag.

```
!!!
= surround '<!--[if !IE]> -->'.html_safe, '<!-- <![endif]-->'.html_safe do
  %html.no-js{:lang => 'en'}
    %head
    %body
```

Could be confusing the `surround` method by having multiple tags appended instead of nested...  Worth a try!

Comment: thanks for trying to figure out solution, I tried with you said but it didn't worked well, the output was this: 
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if !IE]> --><html class='no-js' lang='en'>
  <head>..</head>
  <body>..</body>
</html><!-- <![endif]-->'

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misinterpreted your question.  I don't know of a way to get exactly what you're looking for.  Best of luck!