# Html to Haml conversion javascript

Tags: javascript, html, haml

I have this html code. I want it to convert to haml format.
        -->

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>

    <!--<![endif]-->
```

This is how I convert it to haml.

```
/ [if !IE]>
  :javascript
    window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
/ <![endif]
```

but I got this error Illegal nesting: nesting within a tag that already has content is illegal. Any idea why? or what is the right way to convert this code to haml?

Answer (score 0):

Haml includes support for [IE conditional comments](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#conditional_comments_), the sytax is `/ [cond]`, without the closing `>`

In your first line:

```
/ [if !IE]>
```

the last `>` is being treated as content, and you also nest the `:javascript` filter as content. This is why you get the `nesting within a tag that already has content is illegal` error.

However, you can’t [use the `!IE` condition this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107681/ie-conditional-comments-in-haml/9119406#9119406), you’ll end up with a single comment that all browsers will ignore. You’ll need to no something like this, using literal HTML:

```haml
<!--[if !IE]> -->
:javascript
  window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
<!-- <![endif]-->
```