# Conditionally avoid using Application.css in HAML layout with Asset Pipeline? (IE9 4096)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, haml

I'm working on a project that is fighting the IE 9 4096 rule limit bug. I'm trying to include all of the css that should be included by the manifest in an if IE 9 block:

```
<!--[if !(IE 9)]> -->
= stylesheet_link_tag  "application.css", :media => "all"
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>
= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet1.css", :media => "all"
= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet2.css", :media => "all"
= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet3.css", :media => "all"
<![endif]-->
```

The problem seems to that either rake or Asset Pipeline or something seems to be injecting the application file invisible at the end of the [if IE 9] block.

**TO BE CLEAR, THIS IS THE QUESTION, IT'S NOT ABOUT CONDITIONAL HAML***

It seems as though application.css is always required. Is this the case?

Is there a way to block it from getting injected when the HAML is compiled? (:plain works, but is hacky. you have to maintain a list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107681/ie-conditional-comments-in-haml) led me to the answer. I used `:plain` to encapsulate the [if IE 9]. That prevented whatever weird processing was injecting application.css again. While it fixes it for now, I don't consider this maintainable in the long run.

```
:plain
  <!--[if IE 9]>
  = stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet1.css", :media => "all"
  = stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet2.css", :media => "all"
  = stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet3.css", :media => "all"
  ...many more...
  <![endif]-->
```